# PyGi: How to use a GTKListBox with a GTKListStore?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I am very new to GTK and Gnome app development, so apologies for my naiveté. (My development language is Python). I would like to use a `ListBox` to display some data, and the individual row views will be quite complicated (i.e. composed of multiple different widgets). As a result I would prefer not to use a `TreeView`, because that will require a bunch of custom drawing/event handling. I noticed that `ListBox` has a `bind_model` method, but it appears I can't use it to bind a `ListStore` model, even thought `ListStore` implements the `ListModel` interface. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Comment: The `Gtk.ListStore` is for `Gtk.TreeView`s. You need to use a `Gio.ListStore` for `Gtk.ListBox.bind_model()`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple exampe:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GObject
import sys

class Item(GObject.GObject):

    text = GObject.property(type = str)

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):        
        item1 = Item()
        item1.text = "Hello"
        item2 = Item()
        item2.text = "World"

        liststore = Gio.ListStore()
        liststore.append(item1)
        liststore.append(item2)

        listbox=Gtk.ListBox()
        listbox.bind_model(liststore, self.create_widget_func)

        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.add(listbox)
        window.connect("destroy", self.on_window_destroy)
        window.show_all()

    def create_widget_func(self,item):
        label=Gtk.Label(item.text)
        return label

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():

    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Answer (score -1):

This is condensed code from my open source accounting program.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import os, sys


class GUI :

    def __init__(self):

        listbox = Gtk.ListBox()

        employee_name_label = Gtk.Label("Henry", xalign=1)

        combo = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
        combo.set_property("can-focus", True)
        for name in ["bar", "foo", "python"]:
            combo.append('0', name)

        list_box_row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
        hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=5)
        list_box_row.add(hbox)

        switch = Gtk.Switch()
        switch.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER


        project_time_label = Gtk.Label("0:00:00", xalign=1 )
        project_time_label.set_property('width-chars', 8)


        hbox.pack_start(employee_name_label, True, False, 5)
        hbox.pack_end(project_time_label, False, False, 5)
        hbox.pack_end(switch, False, False, 5)
        hbox.pack_end(combo, False, False, 5)


        listbox.add(list_box_row)

        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.add(listbox)
        window.connect("destroy", self.on_window_destroy)
        window.show_all()

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

def main():
    app = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

It may not answer your question exactly, but it does work and it shows a way to use ListBox. ListBox is a very good choice for complicated setups. In my case I was doing so much operations every second that it crashed Treeviews.